# Issue receiving and storing data in C++

Tags: c++, networking

I have written a server application in C++ that receives a packet of data from a client application (which I have not written myself) and prints the data to the console. The issue is, when I try to receive and store the entire packet body at once, the data is stored incorrectly, however when the packet body is received and stored using multiple callings of recv(), it does store correctly.

Regarding endianness, the client and server are both running on a little endian machine, the client sends data out as little endian, and the server reads it without need for conversion.

**This is the packet that the client application sends to the server application:**

```
00 03 23 00 57 6f 57 00  01 0c 01 f3 16 36 38 78
00 6e 69 57 00 42 47 6e  65 00 00 00 00 7f 00 00
01 05 41 44 4d 49 4e
```

**Here is a structured view of the packet:**

```
cmd             00
error           03
pkt_size        23 00
gamename        57 6f 57 00
version1        01
version2        0c
version3        01
build           f3 16
platform        36 38 78 00
os              6e 69 57 00
country         42 47 6e 65
timezone_bias   00 00 00 00
ip              7f 00 00 01
srp_I_len       05
srp_I           41 44 4d 49 4e
```

**These are the expected results to be printed out by the server application:**

```
cmd:            0
error:          3
pkt_size:       35
gamename:       5730135
version1:       1
version2:       12
version3:       1
build:          5875
platform:       7878710
os:             5728622
country:        1701726018
timezone_bias:  0
ip:             127 0 0 1
srp_I_len:      5
srp_I:          ADMIN
```

**Here is the code which I am having trouble with:**

```
struct packet{
    uint8   cmd;
    uint8   error;
    uint16  pkt_size;
    uint32  gamename;
    uint8   version1;
    uint8   version2;
    uint8   version3;
    uint16  build;
    uint32  platform;
    uint32  os;
    uint32  country;
    uint32  timezone_bias;
    uint8   ip[4];
    uint8   srp_I_len;
    uint8   srp_I[16];
};

packet data;
recv(clientSocket, &data.cmd, 4, 0); // Receive packet header
recv(clientSocket, &data.gamename, 46, 0); // Receive packet body

printf("%d\n", data.cmd);
...
printf("%s\n", data.srp_i);
```

**The result:**

```
cmd:            0
error:          3
pkt_size:       35
gamename:       5730135
version1:       1
version2:       12
version3:       1
build:          13846 (this is where it all goes wrong)
platform:       1466527232
os:             1850163712
country:        101
timezone_bias:  35512
ip:             1 5 65 68
srp_I_len:      77
srp_I:          IN
```

**If I change the code like so:**

```
recv(clientSocket, &data.cmd, 4, 0); // Receive packet header
recv(clientSocket, &data.gamename, 7, 0); // Receive packet body
recv(clientSocket, &data.build, 39, 0); // Receive packet body
```

**The result:**

```
... same expected results
build:          5875 (fixed)
platform:       1768816760 (goes all wrong here instead)
os:             1195507799
country:        25966
timezone_bias:  8323072
ip:             0 1 5 65
srp_I_len:      68
srp_I:          MIN
```

**And if I make one last adjustment to the code, like so:**

```
recv(clientSocket, &data.cmd, 4, 0); // Receive packet header
recv(clientSocket, &data.gamename, 7, 0); // Receive packet body
recv(clientSocket, &data.build, 2, 0); // Receive packet body
recv(clientSocket, &data.platform, 37, 0); // Receive packet body
```

**The result:**

```
... same expected results
build:          5875
platform:       7878710
os:             5728622
country:        1701726018
timezone_bias:  0
ip:             127 0 0 1
srp_I_len:      5
srp_I:          ADMIN
```

By calling recv() multiple times, it received and stores the data exactly as expected. I have absolutely no idea why the data is stored incorrectly when only calling recv() twice. Please, somebody, enlighten me. Thank you.

PS: Sorry for the monster post of ugliness.

Comment: The C compiler left gaps in your `struct packet` for optimization reasons.  However, the packet as sent on the wire did not have any gaps in it.  If I were doing this I would `recv` the packet into a temporay byte buffer then manually read each field from the buffer and write it into my own struct, avoiding all struct alignment issues.  Your code also assumes common endianness with the remote host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the structure as a packed structure to avoid alignment issues;

On windows use `#pragma pack (1)` (see [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1%28v=vs.80%29.aspx))

On gcc use `__attribute__((packed))`

to remove alignment problems.  Actually gcc will support the windows style pragmas for compatibility. Have a look at:

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Structure_002dPacking-Pragmas.html

EDIT

So example code below shows ONE packed structure inside another untouched structure:

When compiled on x86_64-bit platform:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;


uint8_t input[] = {
    0x00,  0x03,  0x23,  0x00,  0x57,  0x6f,  0x57,  0x00,
    0x01,  0x0c,  0x01,  0xf3,  0x16,  0x36,  0x38,  0x78,
    0x00,  0x6e,  0x69,  0x57,  0x00,  0x42,  0x47,  0x6e,
    0x65,  0x00,  0x00,  0x00,  0x00,  0x7f,  0x00,  0x00,
    0x01,  0x05,  0x41,  0x44,  0x4d,  0x49,  0x4e
};

struct __attribute__((packed)) packet{
    uint8_t   cmd;
    uint8_t   error;
    uint16_t  pkt_size;
    uint32_t  gamename;
    uint8_t   version1;
    uint8_t   version2;
    uint8_t   version3;
    uint16_t  build;
    uint32_t  platform;
    uint32_t  os;
    uint32_t  country;
    uint32_t  timezone_bias;
    uint8_t   ip[4];
    uint8_t  srp_I_len;
    uint8_t  srp_I[16];

};

struct data {
    long int foo;
    short a;
    uint8_t b;
    struct packet p;
    uint32_t bar;
};

int main() {
    struct packet p;
    struct data d;

    cout << "in: " << sizeof(input) << ", d: " << sizeof (d) << ", p: " << sizeof(p) << " d.p: " << sizeof(d.p) << endl;
    memset(&p, 0, sizeof(p));
    memcpy(&p, input, sizeof(input));
    cout << (int) p.srp_I_len << endl;
    cout << p.srp_I  << endl;
}

$./foo
in: 39, d: 72, p: 50 d.p: 50
5
ADMIN
```

Comment: I am getting "error: cannot bind packed field 'data.packet::pkt_size' to 'uint16_t&'" and for gamename aswell with 'uint32_t&'.

Comment: can you show your pragma code ? Because it should just work ; it seems that your packet structure is part of another structure?

Comment: I am using GCC so I did this: struct __attribute__((packed)) AuthLogonChallenge{ ... }. The variables in the struct are uint8_t's, uint16_t's and uint32_t's from stdint.h, I typedef'd them to shorten the data type name.

Comment: okay i am going to post some code ... that I KNOW works. I am assuming that you are using c++; (since that's what you marked, but it works in C as well) Hopefully it will give you enough clues to make your situation work... standby

Comment: I used #pragma pack(1), and it works! Thanks a lot. I still don't understand why it was going wrong though, and what the line of code does to help...

Comment: I also posted it with __attribute__((packed)) syntax with some silliness thrown in to ensure that you don't screw up the alignment of other structures (aligned structures are faster!)  Note that it should work fine there as well

Answer (score 0):

The bytes in the structure must be aligned to 4 bytes. You have to introduce some spare variables:

```
struct packet{
    uint8   cmd;
    uint8   error;
    uint16  pkt_size;
    uint32  gamename;
    uint8   version1;
    uint8   version2;
    uint8   version3;
    uint8   spare1;
    uint16  build;
    uint8   spare2;
    uint8   spare3;
    uint32  platform;
    uint32  os;
    uint32  country;
    uint32  timezone_bias;
    uint8   ip[4];
    uint8   srp_I_len;
    uint8   spare4[3];
    uint8   srp_I[16];
};
```

Comment: I've tried adding the spare variables, exactly as you have shown here, however the data is still being stored incorrectly.

Comment: are you sure you implemented this last version? I edited it a couple of times because I made some errors

Comment: Yeah, I put all 4 spares in.